# раздение при помощи метода join

Tags: python, telegram-bot

хочу что б при помощи команды add в телеграмме, вносились данные пользователя в sqlite которые я введу, но сейчас хоть бы вывести данные правильно, не пойму можно сделать так, что б метод Join читал до определенного символа, скажем к примеру до ","

```
@dp.message_handler(Command("add"))
users_id = ' '.join(message.text.split(' ')[1:])
users_name = ' '.join(message.text.split(', ')[1:])
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ID {users_id} с именем {users_name} добавлен, ", parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 3):

Метод `join` будет считывать всю последовательность, которую в нее передают. Если нужно в `join` передать только часть последовательности, то логично будет сделать срез до нужного вам элемента/символа.
В случае с запятой:

```
users_name = ''.join(message.text.split(',')[0])
                                            ^^^
```

Тогда в `join` передадутся все символы строки до запятой.